# jQuery / JavaScript: Check all checkboxes and Check each checkbox to display div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am having a hard time figuring this out. I tried to make a global checkbox that will check all other sub-checkboxes and display a div, which works fine, but the issue is when i try to make each sub-checkboxes check and display the div themselves.

I wrote jquery hide and show for it.

When I check the first sub-checkbox, and check the second; the div displays but when i go back and uncheck the first one, the div closes and one and on due to the hide and show function, how can i do this?

Here is my code below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox-global').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', true);
        else
            $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', false);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox-global').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('.loaded').show(1000);
        else
            $('.loaded').hide(1000);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkbox-group').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('.loaded').show(1000);
        else
            $('.loaded').hide(1000);
    });
});
```

```
     <!-- The Div -->
      <div class="loaded">RESTORE | DELETE</div>

    <!-- The Global Checkbox -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-global" class="checkbox-group">
    <br>

    <!-- The Sub-checkboxes -->
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
```

Comment: what is the exact functionlity? you want to show the div on click of any of the sub checkboxes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for any of the check boxes is checked and if yes don't hide the div
Here is a sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#checkbox-global').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', true);
        $('.loaded').show(1000);
    }
    else {
        $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', false);
        $('.loaded').hide(1000);
    }
});

   $('.checkbox-group').click(function(){
       var cnt = $(".checkbox-group:checked").length;
      if(cnt > 0)
         $('.loaded').show(1000);
      else
         $('.loaded').hide(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `document.ready` multiple times, one is enough. This is to ensure that all DOM structure is ready and you can get the desired element at that point.

following are the points to consider
1) No need to bind click event twice for `checkedLength`, you can put checkbox check/uncheck and div show / hide logic in same click event handler. 
2) You can check if any other checkbox is checked from `checkbox-group`, if none is checked then hide div otherwise show it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox-global').click(function(){
        // check uncheck checkbox as per checked status
        $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

        //show hide div
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
           $('.loaded').show(1000);
        else
          $('.loaded').hide(1000);
    });

    $('.checkbox-group').change(function(){
        //check if checkbox-group have atleast one checkbox checked
        var checkedLength =  $('.checkbox-group:checked').length;
        if(checkedLength > 0)
          $('.loaded').show(1000);
        else
         $('.loaded').hide(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello pls, how can i show the number count of the checkboxes. When i check one and all.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/zef01vs7/):

**HTML**

```
<!-- The Div -->
<div class="loaded">RESTORE | DELETE</div>
<!-- The Global Checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-global" class="checkbox-group">
<br>
<!-- The Sub-checkboxes -->
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $(".loaded").hide();
    $("#checkbox-global").click(function () {
        if ($("#checkbox-global").is(":checked")) {
            $(".checkbox-group").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(".checkbox-group").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });

    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($(".checkbox-group").is(":checked")) {
            $(".loaded").show(1000);
        } else {
            $(".loaded").hide(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello pls, how can i show the number count of the checkboxes. When i check one and all

Comment: @SowemimoBamidele Use the jQuery `.size()` method. For example: `$(":checked").size()` returns the number of checked elements. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var c = $('.checkbox-group').size();  //This line is used to count checkbox
    $('#noc').html(c);
    $('#checkbox-global').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var nocf = $(":checked").size()
            $('#noch').html(nocf);
            $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', true);
            $('.loaded').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', false);
            $('.loaded').hide();
            var nocf = $(":checked").size()
            $('#noch').html(nocf);
        }  
    });

    $('.checkbox-group').click(function(){
        var tom = $('#checkbox-global').is(':checked');
        if(tom == true || $('.checkbox-group').is(':checked')) {
            var nocf = $(":checked").size()
            $('#noch').html(nocf);
            console.log($(":checked").size());  //This line is used to count checked checkbox
            $('.loaded').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.loaded').hide();
            var nocf = $(":checked").size()
            $('#noch').html(nocf);
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Hello pls, how can i show the number count of the checkboxes. When i check one and all

Comment: are you want to count checkbox or check no of checkbox checked

Comment: I want to count the checkbox and display the numbers if each one is checked or checkbox global is checked

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {

    var checked = true;

    $("#all_check").on("change", function() {

        checked = $(this).is(':checked');

        if (checked) {

          $('.dg-img').prop('checked', true);

        }

         else

         {

        $('.dg-img').prop('checked', false);

         }

    });
```